# How do I choose an appropriate number of customers for cluster analysis?

Tags: sas, selection, cluster-analysis, analysis

I am currently doing a customer segmentation project in SAS.

I have identified 2700 customers who are have made a purchase in each of the 4 years I am analysing. For the cluster analysis the more purchases/customer each year the better the data quality is. However as I become more selective over number of purchases needed each year per customer, the less customers can be considered in the cluster analysis.

How should I go about choosing the cutoff point for the number of purchases necessary per customer per year to be considered for analysis. I am struggling with this trade off between data quality and having enough customers for analysis.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: What is you final goal?

Comment: My goal is to segment the consumers into four groups based on their purchase behaviour. The variables for the cluster analysis will be market experience and proneness to promotion.

Comment: So I would suggest you make several cut-offs and then examine the changes. If nothing changes than it does not matter. Or some cut-off is visually better than the other.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try it with varying cut offs and compare the cluster model performance. thanks

Comment: Methodology type questions should be posted on stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct way. It entirely depends on your data.

Clustering such data is "magic" and the results tend to be all but statistically sound. More like random gueses.

Because of this, **always try multiple parameters and carefully inspect the results**. No equation ever will tell you what a good clustering is.